# Replace row values by condition if they are in certain time range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, time-series

I'm trying to replace certain values in a DataFrame row by two conditions. First they must be in a certain time range. Additionally, the value in this time range has to be in a list of values to be replaced.

My best attempt:

```py
df = df[df.between_time('06:00', '20:00')].replace([0, 1, 2, 3], np.nan, inplace=True)
```

This is the error I get:

```
ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object
```

The DataFrame looks like this:

| datetime | vehicles |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 13.0 |
| 2021-01-01 00:15:00 | 9.0 |

And so on...

The main goal is to replace all values between 06:00 and 20:00 (8pm) with NaN, if they're <= 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
```

Firstly convert your 'datetime' column into datetime dtype by(If it is already as datetime[ns] then ignore this step):

```
df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

Then make your 'datetime' column as an index(If it is already as index then ignore this step):

```
df=df.set_index('datetime')
```

Now make use of `between_time()` method and `apply()` method:

```
resultdf=df.between_time('00:06:00', '00:20:00')['vehicles'].apply(lambda x:np.nan if x<=3 else x)
```

Finally:

```
resultdf.values.shape=(2,1)
df.loc[resultdf.index]=resultdf
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output